# Python cgi write to xml generates error 500

Tags: python, xml, cgi

I have a simple script that writes data to an XML file, but when I call it over HTTP I get a 500 error. I managed to write to the XML file before and with the same code so I know that's not the problem. I also checked to see if the data was properly transferred and it is.

I don't know what else I can check / modify.

here's the script:

```
#!C:\Python27\python.exe

import cgi, json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

CONF_FILE = "../data/config.xml" 

data = cgi.FieldStorage()

params = {}
for key in data.keys():
    params[ key ] = data[ key ].value

conf = ET.parse(CONF_FILE)

root = conf.getroot()

cameras = root.find('cameras')
camera = cameras.find("./camera[@id='" + params['id'] + "']")

camera.find('threshold').text = str(params['threshold'])
camera.find('motionDetection').text = str(params['md'])
camera.find('recordTime').text = str(params['rec-time'])

conf.write(CONF_FILE)

print "Content-type: application/json"
print 
print json.dumps(params)
```